# Mysqli functuion running without mysqli_execute being called

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a connection to an API that pulls down all the sessions for an event and adds them to the local database.

I am fairly new to using mysqli so maybe I am missing something. The API is pulling the events properly, and the connection to the db is working, heck it even writes to the DB successfully when I call `firstPull($client, $mysqli)`.

However, when I looked at the database after running `firstPull()`, each session was written to the table twice. After some debugging, I noticed it was happening inside the `saveSessionToDB()` function. Once I commented out `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` it only wrote them once. However, isn't that method the one that actually runs the statement? Which is where my confusion is coming from. Why is the statement being executed when I bind the parameters?

Both `firstPull()` and `saveSessionToDB()` are inside a file called `session-func.php` that houses all the functions that use both database and API features. There are no other functions that use the `mysqli_stmt_execute()` method inside.

The function `firstPull()` is being called using an ajax function inside a file called `admin-functions.php`so I can run it when I press a button on the Admin Controls page. Inside this file I have the following includes:

`include './db.php'; // Database connection and functions
    include './cvent-api.php'; // API connection and functions
    include './session-func.php'; // API and DB functions`

Below are the two functions `firstPull()` and `saveSessionToDB()`.

```
function firstPull($client, $mysqli)
{
$mysqlivar = $mysqli;
$JSONresult = json_decode(json_encode(retrieveSessions($client)), true);
$allSessions = $JSONresult[RetrieveResult][CvObject][ProductDetail];

$y = count($allSessions) - 1;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $y; $x++) {
    $pattern = "/([A-Z][0-9])\s\-\s(.)+/";
    $hasSessionCode = preg_match($pattern, $allSessions[$x][ProductName], $matches);

    if ($matches) {
        $sessCode = $matches[1];
    } else {
        $sessCode = "Nil";
    };

    $session = array(
      "id" => $allSessions[$x][ProductId],
      "sesscode" => $sessCode,
      "name" => $allSessions[$x][ProductName],
      "desc" => strip_tags($allSessions[$x][ProductDescription]),
      "starttime" => $allSessions[$x][StartTime],
      "endtime" => $allSessions[$x][EndTime]
    );

    saveSessionToDB($mysqlivar, $session);
}

echo "Sessions have been pulled down successfully";
closeDB($mysqli);

}



function saveSessionToDB($mysqli, $session) 
{

  if (!$mysqli) {
    echo "Connect failed: %s\n" . mysqli_connect_error() ."";
    exit();
  }

$id= $session['id'];
$sanitized_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $id);
$sesscode= $session['sesscode'];
$sanitized_sesscode = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sesscode);
$name = $session['name'];
$sanitized_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $name);
$desc = $session['desc'];
$sanitized_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $desc);
$starttime = $session['starttime'];
$sanitized_starttime = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $starttime);
$endtime = $session['endtime'];
$sanitized_endtime = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $endtime);

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO sessions (id, sessioncode ,name, description, starttime, endtime ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

if (!$stmt) {
    die('mysqli error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

/* bind parameters statement */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', $sanitized_id, $sanitized_sesscode, $sanitized_name, $sanitized_desc, $sanitized_starttime, $sanitized_endtime);

if (!mysqli_execute($stmt)) {
    die('stmt error: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}

/* execute the statement */
// mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* close statement*/
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

To sum all this up. Why is my statement being executed when `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` is commented out in the `saveSessionToDB()` function? Let me know if you need anymore details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (!mysqli_execute($stmt)) {` executes the statement.

It doesn't matter that it's in a conditional, it has to execute it to evaluate it for "truthiness" for the if.

([`mysqli_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-execute.php) is an alias of `mysqli_stmt_execute`, by the way.)

Comment: Well, that makes total sense! I changed `if (!mysqli_execute($stmt)) {` to `if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {` to make sure I don't miss that again.

Comment: Good idea! I don't usually use mysqli, so I actually had to go to the docs to make sure they were the same thing before answering. It looks like most of the `mysqli_stmt_` functions have `mysqli_` aliases.